# Can't get a footer to stick to the bottom when content of the page is being dynamically rendered

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a quote generator app which in its current form generates fine results on pc but on mobile I get this :
[the quote overlaps the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4OCW.png)

I have used absolute, relative, static and other types of positions but it just doesn;t adhere to the bottom when a long quote appears otherwise its working fine.

Here is the code:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#ffcb8e;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arabesque.png");
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color:#322f3d;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.btn {
  ...

}
.btn:hover {
    ...
}
.btn:active {
...
}

.quote{
  padding:50px 50px 0;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 850px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.name{
  ...
}

.logo{
  ...;
}

.footer{
  display: table-footer-group;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(251, 212, 109, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.footer p{
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #322f3d;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

@media screen and (max-width:460px) {
  .logo{
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
  }

  .quote{
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .name{
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" />
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Created by Kartik Sood</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/jsx" src="../src/index.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easist fix is to edit .footer:
-delete:   display: table-footer-group;
-change:   position: fixed;

however root will collide then with the footer and as such a margin or apdding of 60px at the bottom (your footer height) has to be added.

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#ffcb8e;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arabesque.png");
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color:#322f3d;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.btn {
  ...

}
.btn:hover {
    ...
}
.btn:active {
...
}

.quote{
  padding:50px 50px 0;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 850px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.name{
  ...
}

.logo{
  ...;
}

#root {
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}

.footer{
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(251, 212, 109, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.footer p{

  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #322f3d;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

@media screen and (max-width:460px) {
  .logo{
    height:100px;
    width:150px;
  }

  .quote{
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .name{
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" />
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Created by Kartik Sood</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/jsx" src="../src/index.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that and it still overlaps the text. This is what happens: https://imgur.com/a/lV2F0Ft

Comment: can you link the entire code or your website please, then I take a look into it.

Comment: Sure, you can find it on: github.com/kartiks2k/quote-generator, the website's at quotegenerate.herokuapp.com

Comment: that issue is, that you still use position: absolut instead of position: fixed like mentioned.

Comment: Also your Div "Root" still has no amrgin bottom of at least 46px. that will cause another issue of overlapping if you fix the position line.

Comment: I've tried both setting position to fixed and giving margin to bottom. They just make it float above the specified margin and the problem persists. The code on GitHub is pretty much the same but I've been testing solutions locally.

Comment: well the F12 insepctor on the site you linked clearly shown me that the needed changes have not been made there. Thats why it wont work.

Comment: I just told you i am testing those changes locally. Why would I push those changes to the site when they clearly don't work in the screenshot I have included in the previous comment. You can fork the project and try them yourself if you want.